# Reproduce the "Area path" and "Iteration" controls?

Tags: wpf, tfs, wpf-controls

I'm working on a visual studio package that handles some advanced work item copying scenarios. I was wondering if anyone knew how to reproduce the tree-like 'area path' and 'iteration' controls that are used on work item, for use in my add-in? I am using WPF to build my control.

Comment: Can you reformulate the query or explain it a bit more?

Comment: @Pankaj I want to use the "area path" and "iteration" controls that are used in a work item template in my add-in. In other words, I'd like to be able to select an area and path, in the same way one would select an area and path in a work item, in the independent add-in that I am creating. I was hoping that control was available for reuse. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite a painful collection of bits on the interwebs, since I'm new to WPF, but I recreated it. I found the original XAML for a ComboBox and modified as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:theme="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero" 
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:project="clr-namespace:Project.Utilities">

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="TextBoxBorder"
                         StartPoint="0,0"
                         EndPoint="0,20"
                         MappingMode="Absolute">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#ABADB3"
                          Offset="0.05"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#E2E3EA"
                          Offset="0.07"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#E3E9EF"
                          Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground"
                         StartPoint="0,0"
                         EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3"
                          Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB"
                          Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD"
                          Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD"
                          Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder"
                     Color="#FF707070"/>

    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrowGeometry">M 0 0 L 3.5 4 L 7 0 Z</Geometry>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode"
                Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <theme:ButtonChrome Name="Chrome"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                        RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Path Name="Arrow"
                                  Margin="3,1,0,0"
                                  Fill="Black"
                                  Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </theme:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Chrome"
                                    Property="RenderPressed"
                                    Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow"
                                    Property="Fill"
                                    Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="4,4,21,4"
                               StrokeThickness="1"
                               Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                               StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                               SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTextBox"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop"
                Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth"
                Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight"
                Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode"
                Value="VerticalFirst"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
                Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  Focusable="false"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  Background="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton"
           TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
                Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Focusable"
                Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="ClickMode"
                Value="Press"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <theme:ButtonChrome Name="Chrome"
                                        Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                        RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}"
                                        RoundCorners="false"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Path Name="Arrow"
                                  Margin="0,1,0,0"
                                  Fill="Black"
                                  Data="{StaticResource DownArrowGeometry}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </theme:ButtonChrome>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Chrome"
                                    Property="RenderPressed"
                                    Value="true"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Arrow"
                                    Property="Fill"
                                    Value="#AFAFAF"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxEditableTemplate"
                     TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Grid Name="Placement"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Popup Name="PART_Popup"
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                   AllowsTransparency="true"
                   Placement="Bottom"
                   IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">
                <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw"
                                              Color="Transparent"
                                              MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=Placement,Path=ActualWidth}"
                                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                        <ScrollViewer Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas Height="0" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Rectangle 
                                    Name="OpaqueRect"
                                    Height="{Binding ElementName=DropDownBorder,Path=ActualHeight}" 
                                    Width="{Binding ElementName=DropDownBorder,Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                    Fill="{Binding ElementName=DropDownBorder,Path=Background}" />
                                </Canvas>
                                <ItemsPresenter Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
            </Popup>

            <theme:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Border"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                 RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                 RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"/>
            <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                     Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                     Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTextBox}"
                     IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                          Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Border"
                        Property="RenderFocused"
                        Value="true"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                        Property="Height"
                        Value="95"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                        Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup"
                     Property="Popup.HasDropShadow"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                        Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                        Property="Color"
                        Value="#71000000"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer"
                     Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                     Value="false" >
                <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" 
                        Property="Canvas.Top" 
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer, Path=VerticalOffset}" />
                <Setter TargetName="OpaqueRect" 
                        Property="Canvas.Left" 
                        Value="{Binding ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="Tree"
           TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxFocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility"
                Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding"
                Value="4,3"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode"
                Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
                Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid Name="MainGrid"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"
                                              Width="0"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Popup Name="PART_Popup"
                               AllowsTransparency="true"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               Placement="Bottom"
                               Margin="1"
                               IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}">

                            <theme:SystemDropShadowChrome Name="Shdw"
                                                          Color="Transparent"
                                                          MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid,Path=ActualWidth}"
                                                          MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        BorderThickness="1"
                                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}"
                                        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                                    <ScrollViewer Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                        <TreeView  x:Name="PART_TreeView" ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}">
                                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                                <project:BindableSelectedItemBehavior SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox} }, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNodes}">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                                            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </TreeView>

                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                </Border>
                            </theme:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                        </Popup>
                        <ToggleButton Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter IsHitTestVisible="false"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem, Converter={project:PathConverter}}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger SourceName="PART_Popup"
                                 Property="Popup.HasDropShadow"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                                    Property="Margin"
                                    Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Shdw"
                                    Property="Color"
                                    Value="#71000000"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder"
                                    Property="Height"
                                    Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping"
                                 Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                    Value="false"/>
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer"
                                 Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                                 Value="false" >
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TreeView" 
                                    Property="Canvas.Top" 
                                    Value="{Binding ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer, Path=VerticalOffset}" />
                            <Setter TargetName="PART_TreeView" 
                                    Property="Canvas.Left" 
                                    Value="{Binding ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset}" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="Tag">
                            <Setter Property="SelectedValue" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEditable"
                     Value="true">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
                        Value="false"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding"
                        Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Template"
                        Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I also had to add a behavior and some funky bug stuff with the `IsDropDownOpen` property on the `ComboBox`.

```
public class BindableSelectedItemBehavior : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(BindableSelectedItemBehavior), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnSelectedItemChanged));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += this.OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        if (this.AssociatedObject != null)
        {
            this.AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += this.OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        }
    }

    private static void OnSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.NewValue as TreeViewItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
            item.SetValue(TreeViewItem.IsSelectedProperty, true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        this.SelectedItem = e.NewValue;

        var treeView = (TreeView)sender;
        var control = (FrameworkElement)treeView.TemplatedParent;
        ComboBox combo;

        do
        {
            combo = control as ComboBox;

            if (combo != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        while ((control = (FrameworkElement)control.TemplatedParent) != null);

        if (combo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => combo.IsDropDownOpen = false)); // setting in other ways (XAML) wasn't working as expecting
    }
}
```

and in the actual control

```
...
<ComboBox Name="area" Style="{StaticResource Tree}"/>

...
<ComboBox Name="iteration" Style="{StaticResource Tree}"/>
```

and the control code behind

```
    private void UpdateAreasAndIterations(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.project.SelectedIndex <= 0)
        {
            this.area.Items.Clear();
            this.iteration.Items.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            var project = (Project)this.project.Items[this.project.SelectedIndex];

            this.area.ItemsSource = project.AreaRootNodes;
            this.iteration.ItemsSource = project.IterationRootNodes;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The control is in the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Controls assembly. It's the WorkItemClassificationControl, but it's "internal" which means you won't be able to reference it. I also spoke with one of our developers from the work item tracking client team, and he said that the control wasn't designed to be used outside of Team Explorer (our Visual Studio package).

Comment: /sadness I've been tinkering the last day and a half away attempting to recreate it with a combobox/treeview, I get close, but still haven't perfected it. Thanks!